# MySQL: Is there a way to find out which user called stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.7

Server: MySQL 5.7.14
I am following the Suggestion 1 suggested here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109416/126860

I am trying to find out which user called the stored procedure. But since I am also using a definer. The `CURRENT_USER();` function returns the "definer" user name.

I have tried using `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` to find out who is running the stored procedure. but it doesn't show stored procedures as a separate process.

Is there a way to find the actual user who invoked the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back on `Jan 10, 2012`, I answered [MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897) where I show two function calls:

- [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in mysqld
- [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate by mysqld

Since [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) shows the definer, try using [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user). It might display the MySQL user and the host where that user was coming in from. Please note that this may not work if [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) is an internal thread running the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Yes. User() works when using definers.